# Downloading certain part of audio and continue downloading the rest when reaching a certain point in the audio

Tags: android, ios, node.js, mobile-application, digital-ocean-spaces

I want to create an app for sharing audio files. I want to build native mobile apps and made most of my progress on android with a PHP/MySQL backend so far. But now I want to step up my game and build my backend with Node.js and MongoDB.

Since big audio files take a while do download and can worsen the user experience I wondered if it is possible to just download the first 20% of an audio file. When the user reaches a certain point of the audio it downloads the rest/the next section. Therefore, we do not need to download the entire audio that might never get used. I just wonder if it is that difficult to add another section of the audio while playing without any interruptions.

For some reason I think this is how the big social media apps work but I cannot find any sources on this topic. I don't ask for code but just suggestions and references to help me. Am I on a good track or are there are ways to solve this problem? Also can you recommend to use Digital Ocean Spaces for this task??

Sources for Android and IOS will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by providing a "Range" attribute to the header of the HTTP-Request you are sending to the Digital Ocean space for the desired media file. The "Range" attribute says the number of bytes you want to receive.